# Using iTerm2, how do I enter characters with accent marks?

Tags: unicode, osx-yosemite, non-ascii-characters, iterm2

I have a few friends whose names have letters like 'ö'. In all other places in OS X I can hold down the 'o' and then select 2 in the little popup menu. This does not work in iTerm2. In iTerm2 I get a lot of o's. I have also set in the OS X keyboard text settings some replacements to allow typing a person's initials to be replaced with their name.

Is it possible to get either of these input methods to work with iTerm2?

If those won't work, what are my options? I'm really hoping I'm not required to memorize a bunch of alt+key whatever shortcuts for each different type of accent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the traditional input method:

grave accent (à) – <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

circumflex (â) – <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

acute accept (á) – <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

umlaut ä – <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

tilde (ã) – <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Keyboard & Characters Viewer [System Preferences -> Keyboard] in the menu bar, you could open the Characters Viewer and find the letter you need. This should work with iTerm2, although I have never used that application.